# IRC Reading Sockets

Tags: python, bots, irc

I am making a bot and have most everything ready except input.  I want to have something like this:  "!test word"  and have it output something like "word2".  Here is the code that I am using to output data.  I would also like to find out my username (opername).  Sorry if the indenting is off on the page; it's just fine on my end.

```
while True:

    data = irc.recv ( 4096 )
    if data.find ('PING' ) != -1:
      irc.send ('PONG ' + data.split() [ 1 ] + '\r\n' )

    if data.find ('!quit') != -1:
      irc.send ('QUIT\r\n')

    if data.find ('!enc %s\r\n' % werd) != -1:
      irc.send ("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (channel,werd))
```

Comment: can ou just `find('!test word')`?

Comment: I think I have it.  New problem:  PRIVMSG is not working.

Comment: There's nothing indented under the `while` loop, it can't be fine on your end.

Comment: Meanwhile, even if you get this right, it's going to break as soon as "PING" shows up at bytes 4094-4098. You could write your own simple buffering code, but if you're not looking for high-performance, and don't mind blocking, it's probably much simpler to just call `irc.makefile()`. Especially since IRC is a line-based protocol, so you can just call `readline()` on the result (or just use it as an iterator), and be sure you're dealing with exactly one command at a time.

Comment: Also, `data.find('!enc %s\r\n' % werd)` is going to search for whatever you happened to set `werd` to. Is that actually what you want, or are you trying to make it match any string in that positive, and set `werd` to the value matched?

Comment: OK, what did you find and fix, and when you say "New problem: PRIVMSG is not working", what does "not working" mean?

Comment: PRIVMSG works; still having trouble separating !test <var>

Comment: If you're doing this as a learning exercise, it may be useful. If not, you're probably better of downloading and modifying one of the many Python IRC bots that already exist, or using one of the many IRC-bot libraries. A quick Google should turn up plenty of them.

Answer (score 4):

There's a fundamental flaw in your code that has to be fixed before you can get any further.

IRC is a line-based protocol, but you're not reading line by line. Instead, you're reading up to 4096 bytes at a time. That could return the first half of a line, or the middle third of a line, or the last third of a line followed by two complete lines and the first two characters of the fourth.

If you don't understand why this is a problem: Imagine that one `read` returns something ending in `'\r\nPI'`, and the next one returns something starting with `'NG foo\r\n'`. Neither of those will match your `find('PING')`, so you'll miss the command.

The easiest way around this is to change your loop to something like this:

```
for line in irc.makefile():
```

As a minor note, you probably want `'!quit' in data` rather than `data.find ('!quit') != -1`.

Finally, I don't think this is what you actually want (although I could be wrong):

```
if data.find ('!enc %s\r\n' % werd) != -1:
    irc.send ("PRIVMSG %s :%s\r\n" % (channel,werd))
```

This will work if `werd` is a static string that came from somewhere else, but from your description, it sounds like you want to be able to catch any command `!enc foo\r\n` and return `PRIVMSG #chan: foo\r\n`, and also catch `!enc bar\r\n` and return `PRIVMSG #chan: bar\r\n`, and so on for any other possibility that someone might type. For that, you may want a regular expression, or you may just want slightly more complicated string-processing code (e.g., split `data` by whitespace, and if any element matches `'!enc'`, the next element is the word to send back).

Here's an example of one way to do something that may or may not be like what you're trying to do:

```
m = re.search(r'!enc (.*)\r\n', line)
if m:
    irc.send('PRIVMSG %s: %s\r\n' % (channel, m.group(1)))
```

> I want to have something like this: "!test word" and have it output something like "word2"

OK, so how does it figure out that you want "word2" when given "word"? Whatever the rule is, you obviously have to code that rule up somewhere. Or, if you need help coding it up, you have to describe it to us.

From the comments:

> I just want "!test x". The user enters "!test x", I do stuff to "x" and output the changes

I'm assuming you're using `x` here as a metavariable, not a literal—that is, if the user does `"!test x"` you do stuff to `"x"`, if the user does `"!test y"` you do stuff to `"y"`, etc. If I'm wrong, please let me know.

Obviously the code above isn't going to catch that, because it's searching for "enc" rather than "test". But that's a trivial change:

```
m = re.search(r'!test (.*)\r\n', line)
```

And as for "do stuff" to x before outputting it, `m.group(1)` is the `x` above, so:

```
if m:
    irc.send('PRIVMSG %s: %s\r\n' % (channel, do_stuff_to(m.group(1))))
```

If you're not sure what you're sending, receiving, and parsing, you can always add a print statement to test things out:

```
m = re.search(r'!test (.*)\r\n', line)
print m, m.groups() if m else ''
if m:
    print 'got %s, sending %s' % (m.group(1), do_stuff_to(m.group(1))))
    irc.send('PRIVMSG %s: %s\r\n' % (channel, do_stuff_to(m.group(1))))
```

If you want to watch what's going over the socket, there are two ways to do that: Install [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and use it to spy on the messages on the wire, or set up a fake server using [netcat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netcat). I won't explain the former, because there's too much to explain, and there are already good tutorials. But for the latter, it's as simple as this: Open a terminal and run `nc -kl 8888`. Then have your bot connect to `localhost:8888` instead of the remote server. Watch what the bot sends to you, and type or paste the replies into the terminal window. (On almost any platform but Windows, nc comes built in; on Windows you need to get netcat or ncat from somewhere, but I'm pretty sure the Wikipedia page has links.) If you need to do a lot of debugging, you can set netcat up as a proxy that just forwards messages back and forth between your bot and the real server and prints out everything that passes through.

Comment: I just want "!test x".  The user enters "!test x", I do stuff to "x" and output the changes.

Comment: Does the newly edited version answer your question? I have to admit that I find it very hard to understand what you are and aren't having problems with here. And you still haven't answered the comments on your original post.

Comment: irc.send('PRIVMSG %s: %s\r\n' % (channel, m.group(1)))    isn't sending any data.  I tried sending it with no variables and it still won't send!

Comment: I'm confused. Above, you say "PRIVMSG works; still having trouble separating !test <var>". The code above shows how to separate it, but here you're saying PRIVMSG isn't sending any data. If you can post the complete program somewhere, and your test scenario, maybe someone can help you debug. But you should try debugging it yourself--e.g., just throw a bunch of print statements in to make sure the variables are what you expect at each point.

Comment: One quick thought: Does your `channel` variable include the '#' prefix? And is there any chance it could have a '.' or '*' in it? It's been a while since I wrote IRC code, but if I remember right, `PRIVMSG channel foo` sends to a user named `channel`, not a channel named `#channel`, and `#channel.two` sends to all users whose reverse DNS is `channel.two` rather than to a channel named `#channel.two`… And one last thought, but I'll put it in the answer instead of here.

Comment: privmsg works, the problem is that data.find() != -1: isn't reading m = re.search(r'!test (.*)\r\n', line). How can I read the regex from irc and keep it in "m" ???  Also joining is faulted now?!  `irc.send ("JOIN %s\r\n" % channel)` is there, but not running.  I printed above and below the line; the line was run across but didn't do anything.  PINGPONG works just fine :).  This bot is turning into quite the hassle.  I posted the full code here:  [link](http://pastebin.com/akPJVsmp)

Comment: You're supposed to do the `re.search` instead of the `data.find`, not in addition, although I suppose it doesn't matter if the `find` is returning a nonnegative result. Anyway, what do you mean by "not running"? Are you proxying and logging the output and not seeing that line, or just guessing because you don't seem to join the channel?

Comment: It's just not joining the channel.  It is on the network.  What do you mean using `re.search` instead of `data.find`? I don't follow.  Up top do I use `re = irc.recv ( 4096 )` instead of `data = irc.recv ( 4096 )`  Here is some additional debug code:  [link](http://textdump.net/read/822/).  Should we move this discussion to an instant message?

Comment: It all works but she's still not joining the channel.  I understand your code now :D

Comment: OK, you've got a completely different problem now that's probably more to do with IRC than with Python. Open a new question with your working example that fails to join the channel, and ask how to make the JOIN work. Also, you really do need to try tracing/proxying/wiresharking to see what's going to and from the server. For example, you may be getting a server error and just ignoring it; if you don't log the output, you'll never find that out.

Comment: It stops after setting mode +x

Comment: Again: resolve this question, open a new question, and show us (on the new question, not here) the data going over the wire.